# parallax image not working in safari

Tags: css, parallax

Here is my code for parallax image

```css
body,html{
height:100%;
}

.booking {
    margin-top: 60px;

    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1000x800);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.gray1 {
    background: #252525;
}

.opacity-fl1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding-bottom: 244px;

    padding-top: -200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="booking">
 <div class="opacity-fl1 gray1"></div>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

</section>
```

It is working fine in all browsers except safari (In safari only  background: #252525 is showing). Can someone please explain me what is wrong here?

Thank You.

Comment: just for be sure.. use commas here background-image: url("../img/miami-bg.jpg")

Comment: No luck ! I have tried this too..

Comment: can you make a fiddle? or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

That is working for me and i just added a random picture. Using Safari as well.

```css
body,html{
height:100%;
}

.booking {
    margin-top: 60px;

    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1000x800);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.gray1 {
    background: #252525;
}

.opacity-fl1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding-bottom: 244px;

    padding-top: -200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="booking">
 <div class="opacity-fl1 gray1"></div>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

</section>
```

Comment: No, In other browsers its working fine except safari. Currently I'm using windows os, that might be the reason. @Traver

Comment: Oh ok. I am using safari on a mac. maybe windows os is the issue

Comment: @aCSS You can’t Test Safari on windows because it’s obsolete.  Apple now provide Safari exclusively on Mac 